# Show the identity

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a differentiable function. The function $F:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $F(x+iy):=f(x,y)$ is given and the "partial derivative" operator is defined as follows:

$\partial _z F(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y))$

$\partial _\overline{z} F(x+iy)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y))$

Prove that $\frac{F^{(i)}(z)}{i!}z^i=\sum_{|\alpha|= i} \frac{1}{\alpha_1!\alpha_2!}(\partial _z^{\alpha_1} \partial _\overline{z}^{\alpha_2}F)(0)z^{\alpha_1}\overline{z}^{\alpha_2} + o(|z|^i)$ for every function $f$ that is $k>i$ times continuously differentiable.

The thing is, I'm not really sure what happens to the partial derivative operators that were defined when combined more times. And generally any hint as to what would be the idea how to solve this would be appreciated. My attempt was to substitute $f$ on the left hand side but I get stuck when I get to evaluating the right hand side.

Edit: I forgot to mention that $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^2$ and $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$

Comment: also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423089/taylor-expansion-in-the-complex-plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, this is a corollary of Taylor's theorem with Wirtinger Derivations.
An answer to this problem is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925518/proof-of-taylors-theorem-with-wirtinger-derivatives-complex-coordinates).